# Eclipse: workspace is completely invisible

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, playframework

Something quite strange has happened: The whole Eclipse main window disappeared while I was debugging a Play Framework project. The Eclipse symbol in the applications bar still shows up as usual (from where I still can force Eclipse to quit).

My System (Ubuntu 14.04.) still behaves as if Eclipse was there, e. g. other applications get unfocused when choosing Eclipse in the applications bar. Meanwhile I have re-started Eclipse (that didn't help) and even re-started Ubuntu (still the same behaviour).

When I start Eclipse the workspace selection window shows regularly up. If I select another workspace, it also shows up regularly (I have created a second one to test that). Eclipse even still reacts properly on any shortcut as well as well as F10 & F11. It seems like the Eclipse main application window was "transparent". Therefore I assume that it is a problem of Eclipse resp. its workspace rather than an Ubuntu problem.

Does anybody have an idea where to maybe re-configure the workspace? Or is there even a secret function for all that?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I was able to re-get the window: I clicked on a shadow effect that sometimes showed up. I resized that shadow with my mouse. As an effect the Eclipse window top bar (the one above the menu) showed up again. Afterwards I could "pull out" the window from the bar - and there it all was again... But I have still no idea, how that happened - and what might be the solution if someone runs into that issue without having a shadow.